# Maximum Subarray with elimination

Tags: algorithm, arrays

I know how to find the maximum contiguous subarray of an array in O(n).
However the 2nd problem in the following link asks to find the maximum contiguous subarray when some of the elements (k) can be eliminated:
http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2011/inoi2011/inoi2011-qpaper.pdf
I can't seem to find an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Can you show your inefficient way?

Comment: If you understand how the contiguous-subarray solution works, you should be able to modify it ever so slightly for the contiguous-subarray-with-some-holes case. The complexity of the latter is actually O(N log K). No more hints, this figure is a dead giveaway.

Comment: after looking at your comment, the problem became very easy. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the constraints I believe doing a O(N^2) solution will do. I will not tell you how to solve the problem but will give you some hints:

1. Note that the numbers are quite limited in value - they may only be in the range [-10^4, 10^4] this makes it possible to have an array that counts how many numbers you have with a given value(in the whole array or only in a given interval)
2. Iterate over the lengths of the subarray you will be choosing and solve the problem for each length in linear time
3. Note that for a given array you will always discard the k values that are smallest OR all the negative numbers in the subarray if they are less than k

Hope this will help you to solve the problem.

Comment: `Given the constraints I believe doing a O(N^2) solution will do` In the worst case, N can be 10^4 - which is a bit borderline and may not pass the time limit.

Comment: @nhahtdh I usually go for a N^2 solution in 2 sec time limits. Most of the online judge systems I have seen pass even with 1 billion operations or more in 2 secs. I believe this solution will be fast enough. Also please note the solution I propose is quite simple computation wise so it will really use only about 2 * 10^8 **simple** operations. Should do I believe.

Comment: Fair enough if you say so - I rarely venture near the time limit myself so I don't really know.

Answer (score 1):

there is an O(N.K) dynamic programming solution:

let `d[i][j]` (0<=`i`<=N, 0<=`j`<=K) be the maximum sum of any (possibly empty) sub-array ending with `i`th element by eliminating `j` elements.

initial values:
`d[0][j] = 0` for 0<=`j`<=K

updating dynamic values:

```
for i = 1 to N:
     d[i][0] = max (d[i-1][0]+a[i], 0)
     for j = 1 to K:
         d[i][j] = max(d[i-1][j]+a[i], d[i-1][j-1])
```

and solution is `max{d[N][j]}` for 0<=`j`<=K